# Can "beamer" mean "projector"?

Tags: meaning, false-friends

I've lived under the impression that the word *beamer* is an American slang word for a BMW vehicle and a false friend to German speakers: *beamer* does not mean *projector*.

Recently though, I heard an American¹ use the term *beamer* to mean *projector*. I asked her about it and she said that *beamer* can indeed mean *projector* in American English.

Is that true? Is it valid in American and/or British English to use *beamer* to refer to a projector?

I assume it would be a rather recent or localized development since Merriam-Webster [does not list that meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beamer). Neither does the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beamer). Also [painfulenglish.com's blog entry](https://painfulenglish.com/2013/05/08/english-beamer-projector/) from 2013 labels the usage a "mistake".

On the other hand, both the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beamer) and the [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/beamer) state that *beamer* means *data projector*, as [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) helpfully pointed out in the comments.

---

¹ <sub>That's how she introduced herself and she did sound like a native speaker to me.</sub>

Comment: Hello, Matthias. Reasonable research on ELU would be to look up 'beamer' in English dictionaries (and give linked quotes). Wiktionary has a useful entry, but I'd start with AHD, Collins, CED, ODO say.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, I've never heard a projector called a *beamer* - it's always a BMW (a projector does *beam* a picture onto a surface though, so I might understand what was meant if in context).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree. I'm aware that *projector* is not one of the English meanings listed in the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beamer) I linked in the question.

Comment: I am American.  I have not heard "beamer" used for projector.  However there is some well-known software called "Beamer" used to prepare the images for use with a projector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX) .  What does that mean?  Maybe some English speakers do use "beamer" for a projector;  or maybe that software was named by Germans...

Comment: '(and give linked quotes)' would mean mentioning Wiktionary in the body text and giving the actual quote. Visitors should only need to check links for accuracy, not content. // 'PainfulEnglish' has an article mentioning this word; the labelling of the usage as a 'pseudo-anglicism' (I'd agree) is given at Wiktionary; M-W and Collins don't mention the usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I see, thanks for the info. I've restructured the question a bit to make it clearer that there are clues that it's really a false friend.

Comment: Note that amongst BMW enthusiasts "beamer" refers to BMW motorcycles only: they say "bimmer" to refer to BMW cars.  I find this somewhat ridiculous, but apparently both the BMW bike and car owners want to make it clear that they belong to the "right" category. (Heaven forbid someone might think you ride a motorcycle when really you drive a BMW car.)

Comment: Collins, Lexico, M-W, and AHD don't give the sense. Macmillan does, but flags it as 'informal'. Confusingly, CED also gives the sense ('data projector'), then gives two examples using two other senses (textile equipment- and boat-associated). Among more immediacy-sensitive works, Wiktionary gives the caveated article, while UD doesn't give the sense as far as I can see. // FWIW, I've never encountered the sense (but my lecture-theatre days are long gone). /// No wonder you're confused. I'd treat it as 'emerging; use with caution (if at all)'.

Comment: I haven't gone searching for any evidence to back this up, but I've always thought that when referring to the car, it's spelled *Beemer*....

Comment: I've seen *beamer* as a synonym for *raygun*.

Comment: @nnnnnn where are you, because IME in the UK "beamer" is more often a BMW *car*, a motorbike might just be a "BM"

Comment: @Hellion - The spelling I'm familiar with is "bimmer."  It's how I saw it written in a magazine article once and I made a mental note of it.

Comment: No, no, no!!  "Beamer" means "IBMer"!!!

Comment: Hey, some evidence!  [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beemer) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beemer) both say "beemer" (but both also say "also beamer").

Comment: I had an American client in 2002 who wanted to use the term "Beamer" to name a product, the rationale being that everyone would associate that word with a projector, and the software involved "shone a light" on lots of important information. I had never heard the term used in that context at the time. To me a "Beamer" was a BMW.

Comment: Although OED3 does include a citation from 1962 for the cricketing sense of the word, the **first** sense is *1. A person who works with a beam; e.g. one who arranges yarn on the beam of the loom,* which I doubt will remain in first place when they eventually get round to revising it.

Comment: @ChrisH - I'm Australian, but beamer versus bimmer was first explained to me by an English woman who drove a BMW. I think the distinction is pretentious, but there are plenty of [articles explaining it](https://www.motoroids.com/news/beamer-vs-bimmer-we-clear-the-confusion/).

Comment: @nnnnnn there may well be a difference between those who own them and the rest of the population, or perhaps regional variations within the UK. Or maybe its my age leading them to be associated with London yuppies - who seem to prefer "beamer" (in a casual search).

Comment: @ChrisH - I think there is a difference in the language used by enthusiasts who belong to car or motorcycle clubs and regular owners who like the vehicles but don't spend much time thinking about them.

Answer (score 7):

"Beamer" is in use by native  *German* speakers, including in English (a German dictionary translates it as *projector*).  In speech this pseudo-English word is common, probably more so than the more formal "Videoprojektor". As projectors have long been in use in academia and most German academics can and regularly do speak good or excellent English, a slight misuse of an English word (false friend) can persist in this sector (and related ones - German engineers use the same false friend in English).  Colleagues can easily pick up on the term if they're unfamiliar with an alternative (and new graduates in particular haven't often need a term for the box that puts the picture on the screen).

So it's an error, but a comprehensible one, especially where there are Germans around, such as in UK universities. The LaTeX package *beamer*  was started by a German; its existence probably helps propagate the usage.

Comment: The fact that [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beamer) lists the sense?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good catch. I didn't find a dictionary entry with this sense. Perhaps you should answer with that if it's becoming accepted.

Comment: I have, in a comment because the acceptability is indeterminate at the present time. We don't have a lexis czar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's fair enough.  These "usage" cases for modern words can be tricky to support with much in the way of references

Comment: But checking the 3 say dictionaries OP hasn't checked in (or that's the desired situation) seems the only way to give a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4):

The article "[What Is Difference Between a Beamer & a Multimedia Projector?](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-difference-between-a-beamer-a-multimedia-projector)" by Sarah Clark explains it.

It states:

> "Beamer" is a word used in European countries that is synonymous with
>   "projector." A European beamer has the same standard equipment and
>   serves the same purposes as an American [multimedia] projector.

It also states:

> There is no difference between a beamer and a multimedia projector,
>   except for their names. Of course, there are differences between the
>   functions and capabilities of all projectors, but those differences
>   are determined by brand and style.

So, the word *beamer* is European English and refers specifically to a multimedia projector, not just any projector.  Americans probably won't know what you mean if you use "beamer" to mean that unless you're standing right in front of one and are pointing at it while calling it that.

Actually, the word I use and everyone I've heard use, like at the high school  (American ) where I work, is "proxima," which I think came from a name brand, kind of like "kleenex."  I say "proxima" to mean a projector that hooks up to a computer as opposed to saying "projector" because "projector" is taken as meaning a film projector, so if I ask the A/V Department to bring me a "projector" third period, they'll bring me a film projector ️. I have to ask for a "proxima" if I want them to bring me a multimedia projector.  But maybe that's just where I am, jargon at my work, because it's not like I talk about this stuff outside of work to know what other people call it. I wonder what they'd do if I asked them for a "beamer"?

Answer (score 0):

In the UK a projector is called a projector.

I have heard beamer used in the Netherlands and Belgium for a projector. Beamer for a projector just sounds weird to me.

A beamer is slang for a BMW card in the UK. "That's a nice beamer you've got."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  This answer would benefit from citing research; as it stands, it reads more like a comment or an opinion.  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site and read through the [help].